# how to bind the border-color property in template similar to background color

Tags: javascript, css, html

Bind border top & bottom color similar to background color

```
<div class="hello" data-bind="click: showData, style: { background-color: dataColor }">
```

how to add border top and border bottom color also same as background color - dataColor ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="hello" data-bind="click: showData, style: { background-color: dataColor, border-top-color: datacolor, border-bottom-color: datacolor }">
```

is what you re looking for i think

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<div class="hello" data-bind="click: showData, style: { background-color: dataColor, borderBottom: '1px solid '+dataColor, borderTop: '1px solid '+dataColor }">
```